# Can't take this weird message out of my terminal when coding C with VS Code (Ubuntu)

Tags: c, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to code with C using VS Code on Ubuntu. I downloaded the C/C++ extension and CodeRunner, but I was getting the following error:

```
gcc: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

Then I ran this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

The code seems to run just fine now, but I'm still getting this weird message every time:

```
[1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-ufmjt3ry.1qc" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-occoya1a.mmu"
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am missing?

Comment: I think it indicates that GDB is being used to run the program, but it is run by a shell in background with I/O redirection and options to tell GDB that it is running in a background session.  When GDB finishes, the shell running GDB reports that the job has finished.  You can certainly ignore the message — it does not indicate a problem.  OTOH, you (not unreasonably) want to get rid of the message, and there, I'm sorry to say, I can't help you.

Comment: Presumably you have enabled something in the settings which you shouldn't have. Alas, we have no insight into that. Can you just zap the settings and start over?

Comment: you probably just need to configure intellisense https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/configure-intellisense#:~:text=Open%20your%20IntelliSense%20configuration%20by,using%20to%20build%20your%20project.

Comment: I think that is just showing you how the debugger is being executed, that is a normal thing to see... if you run the executable that will not be output, just a debugger ide interface thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to reinstall the build-essential package (if there are some missing files) with: 
`sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential` 
or even to try to reinstall GCC: 
`sudo apt install --reinstall gcc`